# React-sketch is giving an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.getPrototypeOf"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, create-react-app, typescript-typings

I am using a package called react-sketch. I have created a new react typescript app using CRA command `npx create-react-app app-name --template typescript`. And this is the only file changes that I have in `App.tsx`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { SketchField, Tools } from 'react-sketch';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
      <SketchField width="100%" height="100%" widthCorrection={0} tool={Tools.Pencil} lineColor="#3182CE" lineWidth={3} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Also since this package doesn't have @types, I created a file called types.d.ts and added this line to it

```
declare module 'react-sketch';
```

**Problem**

Now when I run `npm start`, its working perfectly fine. However if I do `npm build`(which is basically react-scripts build), and then do `serve -s build`, then in browser console window, I am getting this error

```
utils.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (utils.js:48)
    at a ((index):1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (URL.js:4)
    at a ((index):1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (webidl2js-wrapper.js:3)
    at a ((index):1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:3)
    at a ((index):1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (api.js:7)
(anonymous) @ utils.js:48
a @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ URL.js:4
a @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ webidl2js-wrapper.js:3
a @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ index.js:3
a @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ api.js:7
(anonymous) @ 2.8c3dddb9.chunk.js:2
a @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
a @ (index):1
1087 @ main.a155cba6.chunk.js:1
a @ (index):1
r @ (index):1
t @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ main.a155cba6.chunk.js:1
```

Since this is a third party package, I am not sure how to fix it. If there is a way to fix this issue, I would like to raise a PR to that open source repo or just use that fix myself until this gets fixed in that package. How should I debug this further?

If you want to simulate this, just create a new react typescript app using CRA and then just copy the code that I gave.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is by far not the optimal solution but it's "a" solution that allowed me to successfully create a build for a project that uses react-sketch. What I basically did was cloning the react-sketch repository, and within my project under components created a folder named "ReactSketch" and copied there all the files from the [src](https://github.com/tbolis/react-sketch/tree/master/src) folder in the react-sketch repository, then everywhere I was importing from the npm package
`import {SketchField, Tools} from 'react-sketch';` I replaced it with `import {SketchField, Tools} from '......components/ReactSketch';` to import it from the component folder, so basically I copied the whole source of the components in my project, that did the trick, you just have to install fabric which seems to be the only dependency it uses.